# garbled html email

Tags: c#, email

I'm sending the following html content (pasted below) using the .net framework 4.0 using the following code:

```
    public void sendHTMLMessage() 
    {
        From = constants.GetValue(EnvironmentVariables.ConstantNames.EMAILFROM);
        MailMessage mail = SetMailMessageParameters();
        smpt = new SmtpClient(constants.GetValue(EnvironmentVariables.ConstantNames.SMTP));
        Utils.EnvironmentLogger.WriteToMessageLog("Sending email message: " + Subject);

        smpt.Send(mail);

    }
    private MailMessage SetMailMessageParameters()
    {

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.Subject = Subject;
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(From);
        List<string> ToArray = Utils.GetArrayFromConstantsClass(To);
        foreach (string element in ToArray)
        {
             mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(element));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Attachment))
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Attachment));
        }
        return mail;
    }
```

I'm basically just sending a simple e-mail and it works most of the time, but when the HTML gets long the email I receive is just a bunch of junk:

JVBERi0xLjQKMSAwIG9iago8PAovVGl0bGUgKP7/AEwAaQBnAGgAdABpAG4AZwAgAEQA
aQBnAGkAdABhAGwAIABDAG8AYwBrAHAAaQB0KQovQ3JlYXRvciAo/v8AdwBrAGgAdABt
AGwAdABvAHAAZABmACAAMAAuADEAMgAuADEpCi9Qcm9kdWNlciAo/v8AUQB0ACAANAAu
ADgALgA2KQovQ3JlYXRpb25EYXRlIChEOjIwMTQwNzA4MTAwMDA4LTA0JzAwJykKPj4K

and goes on and on...I have tried different encoding and can't seem to figure out what the issue is. I also tried targeting .net 4.5 and I get the same issue. The HTML opens just fine in a web browser, and I can even send the html through outlook and it works just fine. It's just when I send through the code that it breaks. The other thing that is interesting, if I just send one or two tables (shown below) it sends just fine, but if I send the same table duplicated about 30 times that's when it sends the garbled mess. It does the same thing if I try to simply attach the HTML to the email. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*EDIT* I opened the html email while listening with Fiddler and got the following header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 12:23:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (CentOS)
Content-Disposition: inline;filename*=UTF-8''Daily_Sales_Summary_gbl7-8-2014.html
Cache-control: private
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=945
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerLIBRARIES_PRD_WEB1=2833575683.20480.0000; expires=Fri, 11-Jul-2014 00:23:51 GMT; path=/
```

Here is the content of the HTML File:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Table Email Test</title>
    </head>
        <style type="text/css">

        body
        {

            font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, Univers;
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 12pt;
            text-align: left;
        }

        b
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    div.tableContainer
    {
        font-size: 8pt;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    div.tableContainer th
    {
        font-size: 8pt;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #BBC3E2;
        color: #000000;
        border-color: #808080;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 3;
        padding-left: 3;
        cursor: default;
    }

    div.tableContainer td
    {
        font-size: 9pt;
        text-align: right;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background-color: #F1EEE3;
        color: #000000;
        border-color: #808080;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 3px;
        padding-left: 3px;
    }

    div.tableContainer td.locked, div.tableContainer th.locked
    {
        background-color: #BBC3E2;
        text-align: left;
        color: #000000;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div.tableContainer tr.total
    {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

        </style>
    <body>

    <div class="tableContainer" id="data">
Day<br>Sales<br>Details<br><br>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: auto">
<tbody>
<tr><th class="locked">&nbsp;</th><th>Value<br>1</th><th>Value<br>2</th><th>VAlue<br>3</th><th>Value</th><th>Value</th><th>Value</th><th>Value<br>value</th><th>value<br>value</th><th>value<br>$</th><th>value<br>value</th></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">--Line2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">--Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">--Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>####</td><td>0.0</td><td>3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>11</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>6</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>4</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>-</td><td>0.0</td><td>0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>7</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>8</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>8</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked"><b>Line3</b></td><td><b>0.0</b></td><td><b>0.0</b></td><td><b>0.0</b></td><td><b>0%</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0%</b></td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>
Day<br>Sales<br>Details<br><br>
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: auto">
<tbody>
<tr><th class="locked">&nbsp;</th><th>Value<br>1</th><th>Value<br>2</th><th>VAlue<br>3</th><th>Value</th><th>Value</th><th>Value</th><th>Value<br>value</th><th>value<br>value</th><th>value<br>$</th><th>value<br>value</th></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">--Line2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">--Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">--Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>####</td><td>0.0</td><td>3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>11</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>6</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>4</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>-</td><td>0.0</td><td>0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>2</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>1</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">-Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>7</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>8</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">Line3</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0.0</td><td>8</td><td>0.0</td><td>0%</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked">&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td class="locked"><b>Line3</b></td><td><b>0.0</b></td><td><b>0.0</b></td><td><b>0.0</b></td><td><b>0%</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0</b></td><td><b>0%</b></td></tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<br>data is effective for close of previous business day<br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Capture your email message in Fiddler or a packet sniffer, and tell us the HTTP headers.

Comment: I downloaded Fiddler but was unable to get it to see the e-mail I'm sending/receiving. I've never used the tool before. It seems to work fine capturing all my browser activity, but when I send the e-mail I get nothing. Is there some settings I have to adjust for it to see an e-mail sent?

Comment: Fiddler is a browser plug-in; you have to open the email in a web browser.

Comment: OK I added the headers above, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Use smtpdev. It's a stand alone mailserver that you can run locally. Handy for inspecting your email messages when developing. This way you can determine if it's your code or something fancy is going on on the mailserver.
http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/

Comment: The random text seems Base64Encoded to me, which is the format the attachment is sent as, try to remove the attachment and see if it works. If it does, probably you'll need to check how you send attachments.

Comment: Add the HTML to the body instead of as an attachment.

Comment: Also, the `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` need to be in `using` blocks: `using (MailMessage mail = SetMailMessageParameters()){using (smtp = new SmtpClient(...)){...smtp.Send(mail);}}`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok, there is no attachment being added to this e-mail, all the html is added through the "mail.Body = Body;" the attachment string is null. Thanks for the tip on "using" I suppose that will free up the resources when the message is sent. (although shouldn't make a difference in my case since the program exits right after sending the e-mail)

Comment: I'm checking out smtpdev now. looks promising.

Comment: Ok, after using smtpdev, the emails all come out OK, so now I'm guessing it is something on the exchange server that is causing the issue (which I have no control over) any exchange server guys around who might know what is going on?

Comment: Well, after further analysis, the smtpdev is showing the issue. When I click on the "View" button, the email opens in the default e-mail client without any problem, but when I click on "inspect" the source shows the same garbled mess I get in my inbox normally. When I look at the body there is no html content at all. I feel like I'm getting closer to the problem. anyone have any other thoughts?

Comment: smtpdev saved me! thanks for that one @W0ut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your help. I found out what was causing the issue, although I'm not sure why this fixed the problem. When I change the code to use seven bit encoding it sends the e-mail without any issue. I would love to hear any reason to why this fixes the problem. It feels like a band aid fix. It must have something to do with exchange. Also not sure why I was getting the garbled text even when not sending an attachment. here is the code to fix:

```
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment(this.Attachment);
            attachment.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Something; your ISP, the POP server, perhaps even `SmtpClient.Send` is GZipping the HTTP payload. This is allowed in HTTP. From the `Server: Apache/2.2.21 (CentOS)` I suspect it is the HTTP server.

Any compliant HTTP client should un-GZip the payload when received with this header. The standard .NET `HttpClient` class will do this.

What is “receiving” the email? A program you wrote? It has to un-GZip the payload. Or contact your server admin and see if there is some way to tell it not to GZip large payloads.

Comment: I'm receiving the email via outlook which is hooked to an exchange server. I was unable to use fiddler to capture the message as it comes into the server so I put it up on a centos server and opened via IE. So I'm not sure if the gzip piece applies or not. This is really uncharted territory for me right now though.